# Why there is RC filter between optocoupler and schmitt trigger?

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, schmitt-trigger

I want to use schmitt trigger after optocoupler to have clean signal and connect it to MCU.why there is RC filter between optocoupler and schmitt trigger in many designs?

How should i connect optocoupler to schmitt trigger ic (74hc14)?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the RC filter is to filter any spikes that may show up on the signal line.  Whether such a filter is needed depends upon your environment and the distance between the opto's output transistor and the device it's feeding.

The Schmitt trigger is used because the opto's output waveform, particularly when turning OFF, has slow edge speeds that may violate the transition time requirement of whatever the opto's output is being fed into.

If the opto is close to the 'HC14, I don't think the cap is needed.  But you still need a pullup to VCC on the opto's output since that is probably open collector.

Comment: ,Thank you!. I see in many designs the opto and HC14 next to each other and still RC filter between them.I want to connect opto's collector with 1K to HC14 in ,and Place 10K pull up on opto's collector,then connect HC14 with 1K to MCU , should i place pull on MCU input?Does the circuit i describe, right?please add schematic